# Unity score text gets upadated inside unity editor but does not get updated in a real device

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Scoremanager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static Scoremanager instance;
    public int Score;
    void Awake(){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        }

    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Score = 0;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Score", 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
     public void IncrementScore(){
        Score++;

    }
    public void StopScore(){
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("HighScore", Score);
        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore")){

            if (Score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HighScore")) {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("HighScore", Score);

            }
        }
        else{
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("HighScore", Score);
    }
}
```

The game runs well in the unity editor game view and the score text gets updated, but when i install the game in a real device,the score text does not get updated.Where am I going wrong guys?

Comment: What calls `IncrementScore`?  The code you've posted doesn't look like it would even compile, your braces are way off.

Comment: The Increment score is called from another script.

Comment: You're still missing a closing brace, and you haven't answered the important question, how are these functions called?

Comment: The Increment score is called from another script.The score increments well when when I ran the game in the unity game view,but when i ran the game in a real device the score does not increment.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int Score{
        get{ 
           return PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Score", 0);
        }set{ 
           PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Score", value);
           if (HighScore < value) {
               PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("HighScore", value);
           }
        }
    }

    public static int HighScore{
        get{ 
           return PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HighScore", 0);
        }
    }

    void Start(){
       Score = 0;
    }
}

public class AnotherScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void IncreaseScore(){
        ScoreManager.Score++;

        Debug.Log (ScoreManager.Score);
        Debug.Log (ScoreManager.HighScore);
    }
}
```

There is a way to do it and you can easily manage your game score.